# how to make two level select option category and subcategory with attribute required?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to make two level SELECT OPTION category and subcategory - all level must required

```
<select id="category" required>
    <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option class="Volvo" value="1">Volvo</option>
    <option class="Saab" value="2">Saab</option>
    <option class="Opel" value="3">Opel</option>
    <option class="Audi" value="4">Audi</option>
</select> 


 <select id="subcategory" required>
  <optgroup class="Volvo">
    <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="44">XC60</option>
    <option value="55">XC90</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="Saab">
    <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="66">Saab 9XX</option>
    <option value="77">Saab Aero-X</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="Opel">
    <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="88">Corsa A</option>
    <option value="99">Corsa B</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="Audi">
    <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="616">Audi A4</option>
    <option value="717">Audi A8</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

i need samthing like this

[image]

with javascript or jquery ?

i don't now how works javascript and i need help thanks

Comment: When you say *"sub-level"*, do mean a list nested within a list? BTW you must post the JS/jQ code that you tried using but failed. Include any errors logged and what you expected to happen and what happens instead. Read up on [mcve]

Comment: i don't now how javascript works i need two categories like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxZ0V.jpg

Comment: Why do you think you need JS/jQ? Looking at your image and the code, I see no issue.

Comment: using js jq i need make two level select category and subcategory with atrribute required

Comment: this is demo image from paint

Comment: i have solution but  subcategory is not required https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/e3ysk26b/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plan vanilla JS approach. The magic of showing the red validation comes from the combination of Javascript and CSS.

1. First get the values of the DOM elements by `document.getElementById()`.
2. Get the values of the `<option>` tags.
3. Check if the `.value` of the `<option>` tag is not not the default one.
4. If it is, the add the CSS class to the `<label>` which shows the *Required* text and add the CSS class to add a border to the `<option>` tag.
5. If it is not the default value, then remove the CSS classes from the `<label>` and `<option>`

```js
var categoryChanged = function() {
  var category = document.getElementById('category');
  var subcategory = document.getElementById('subcategory');
  var option = category[category.selectedIndex].value;
  switch (option) {
    case "1":
      subcategory.children[0].style.display = "block";
      subcategory.children[1].style.display = "none";
      subcategory.children[2].style.display = "none";
      subcategory.children[3].style.display = "none";
      break;
    case "2":
      subcategory.children[0].style.display = "none";
      subcategory.children[1].style.display = "block";
      subcategory.children[2].style.display = "none";
      subcategory.children[3].style.display = "none";
      break;
    case "3":
      subcategory.children[0].style.display = "none";
      subcategory.children[1].style.display = "none";
      subcategory.children[2].style.display = "block";
      subcategory.children[3].style.display = "none";
      break;
    case "4":
      subcategory.children[0].style.display = "none";
      subcategory.children[1].style.display = "none";
      subcategory.children[2].style.display = "none";
      subcategory.children[3].style.display = "block";
      break;
  }
}

var validateCategories = function() {
  // Step 1
  var category = document.getElementById('category');
  var subcategory = document.getElementById('subcategory');
  var categoryLabel = document.getElementById('categoryLabel');
  var subcategoryLabel = document.getElementById('subcategoryLabel');
  // Step 2
  var categoryText = category[category.selectedIndex].text; // Don't need this, only shown to show you how to get the text
  var categoryValue = category[category.selectedIndex].value;
  var subcategoryText = subcategory[subcategory.selectedIndex].text; // Don't need this, only shown to show you how to get the text
  var subcategoryValue = subcategory[subcategory.selectedIndex].value;

  // Step 3 for category <option>
  if (categoryValue === "") {
    // Step 4 for category <option>
    category.classList.add('not-valid');
    categoryLabel.classList.remove('validated-label');
    categoryLabel.classList.add('required-label');
  } else {
    // Step 5 for category <option>
    category.classList.remove('not-valid');
    categoryLabel.classList.remove('required-label');
    categoryLabel.classList.add('validated-label');
  }
  // Step 3 for subcategory <option>
  if (subcategoryValue === "") {
    // Step 4 for subcategory <option>
    subcategory.classList.add('not-valid');
    subcategoryLabel.classList.remove('validated-label');
    subcategoryLabel.classList.add('required-label');
  } else {
    // Step 5 for subcategory <option>
    subcategory.classList.remove('not-valid');
    subcategoryLabel.classList.remove('required-label');
    subcategoryLabel.classList.add('validated-label');
  }
};
```

```css
.not-valid {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

.validated-label {
  display: none;
}

.required-label {
  color: red;
  display: visible;
}
```

```html
<label for="category" id="categoryLabel" class="validated-label">Required</label>
<select id="category" onchange="categoryChanged()" required>
    <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option class="Volvo" value="1">Volvo</option>
    <option class="Saab" value="2">Saab</option>
    <option class="Opel" value="3">Opel</option>
    <option class="Audi" value="4">Audi</option>
</select>

<label for="subcategory" id="subcategoryLabel" class="validated-label">Required</label>
<select id="subcategory" required>
  <optgroup class="Volvo" hidden>
    <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="44">XC60</option>
    <option value="55">XC90</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="Saab" hidden>
    <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="66">Saab 9XX</option>
    <option value="77">Saab Aero-X</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="Opel" hidden>
    <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="88">Corsa A</option>
    <option value="99">Corsa B</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup class="Audi" hidden>
    <option value="">select model type</option>
    <option value="616">Audi A4</option>
    <option value="717">Audi A8</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>

<button onclick="validateCategories()">Validate</button>
```

Comment: thank you but this is demo i need like this but subcategory  mast   be required https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/e3ysk26b/3/

Comment: @ZuraKushitashvili So category and subcategory are both required? This is what this solution does. It validates both the category and subcategory to have a value. Granted it doesn't validate if it's in the right subcategory. You need to specify your intentions clearly.